# How to do regex search and then show the regex match as an output in jinja2?

Tags: regex, flask, jinja2

So i have this jinja2 code

```
{% for vul3 in vul.ports_data %}
 {% if vul3.vulnerabilities.vulners and vul3.vulnerabilities.vulners | trim | length %}
<td><label class="badge badge-success">{{ vul3.vulnerabilities.vulners }}</label></td>

  {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

And it shows this output,

```
 cpe:/a:igor_sysoev:nginx:1.20.0: NGINX:CVE-2021-23017 6.8 https://vulners.com/nginx/NGINX:CVE-2021-23017 9A14990B-D52A-56B6-966C-6F35C8B8EB9D 6.8 https://vulners.com/githubexploit/9A14990B-D52A-56B6-966C-6F35C8B8EB9D *EXPLOIT* 1337DAY-ID-36300 6.8 https://vulners.com/zdt/1337DAY-ID-36300 *EXPLOIT* PACKETSTORM:162830 0.0 https://vulners.com/packetstorm/PACKETSTORM:162830 *EXPLOIT*
```

I want to use this regex `CVE-(?:(?:18|19|20|21)[0-9]{2})-[0-9]{5}` to show only the CVEs in this string. Like below

```
CVE-2021-23017
CVE-2021-23017
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could probably have a naive approach and do `vul3.vulnerabilities.vulners.split(':')[6].split(' ')[0]`, if the data you get is coherent and the CVE always comes in the 7th field

Comment: Although it would be better to keep that logic in a view/model as advised in the answer of @David542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is fine and I'd suggest adding this in your view code, or even as an accessor, perhaps:

```
{% for vul3 in vul.ports_data %}
  {% with vulns as vul3.vulnerabilities.vulners|trim|length %}
      {% for cve in vulns.regex_list %}
        <td>...
```

Or whatever you want to call it. I don't believe there is a [built-in Jinja regex method](https://docs.stackstorm.com/reference/jinja.html#regex-match) that returns the list you're looking for, so you'll either want to add a custom filter or just add it in your view/model code which I'd suggest.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if i just pass regex data to this`regex_list` would it work? or how am i supposed to do it?

Comment: @Jevin no you'd either need to create a custom filter in jinja or handle this in your view/model. In flask, you pass it the variable `vul3` right? How does vul3 get the properties of `ports_data` and `vulnerabilities` ? Wherever you give it those properties you should add the regex check.